# PowerBi moving average without dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure where I need the moving average (last n values, iE 2).

```
Avg mfcktransf7 = 

VAR __verkFest       = AVERAGE(LieferscheineUnique[Festigkeit])
VAR __avg            = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(LieferscheineUnique[fci_zu_PA]), 
                        FILTER(ALLSELECTED(LieferscheineUnique), 
                             LieferscheineUnique[MATNR] = MAX (LieferscheineUnique[MATNR])),
                        FILTER(ALLSELECTED(LieferscheineUnique), 
                             LieferscheineUnique[WERKS] = MAX (LieferscheineUnique[WERKS]
                        )) )
VAR __mwtrans        = CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(LieferscheineUnique,LieferscheineUnique[fci_zu_PA] - __avg), LieferscheineUnique[fci_zu_PA] <> BLANK()) 
VAR __result         = __mwtrans + __avg - __verkFest

RETURN
__result
```

As the dates are not continious a default moving average based on dates will show the wrong results.

[image]

How do I accomplish the right moving average?

Here the table:

| Datum | WERK | Sorte_Tech | Avg mfcktransf7 | Expected result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11.01.2022 | H704 | 10091391 | 5,8 | 5,8 |
| 21.01.2022 | H704 | 10091391 | 11,5 | 8,65 |
| 24.01.2022 | H704 | 10091391 | 9 | 10,25 |
| 25.01.2022 | H704 | 10091391 | 5,5 | 7,25 |
| 27.01.2022 | H704 | 10091391 | 14,2 | 9,85 |
| 07.02.2022 | H704 | 10091391 | 11,4 | 12,8 |
| 08.02.2022 | H704 | 10091391 | 8,1 | 9,75 |
| 09.02.2022 | H704 | 10091391 | 12,8 | 10,45 |
| 16.02.2022 | H704 | 10091391 | 11,7 | 12,25 |

Comment: Paste your table as text and someone will be more likely to help.

Comment: Add an Index column and use that for your DAX in place of the Date, or add a moving average column using Power Query.

Comment: Hi Ron, that wont work, as the date will be used as filter and that will change the outcome of my measure. So a dynamic solution is required.

I found a way to calculate an dynamic index:
VAR lastDatewithvalue   = MAX(LieferscheineUnique[Datum]) 
VAR myIndex             = CALCULATE(COUNTAX(LieferscheineUnique,[Avg mfcktransf7]) ,ALLSELECTED(LieferscheineUnique),LieferscheineUnique[Datum] <= lastDatewithvalue)

Next I still need the moving average based on this index. (last n values)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this calculated column that calculates the top `_n` dates per row and averages the values:

```
Moving Avg = 
VAR _current_date = [Datum]
VAR _n = 2
VAR _topn = 
    TOPN ( 
        _n , 
        CALCULATETABLE ( 
            VALUES ( 'Table'[Datum] ) , 
            ALLEXCEPT ( 
                'Table' , 
                'Table'[WERK] , 
                'Table'[Sorte_Tech]
            ) , 
            'Table'[Datum] <= _current_date 
        ) , 
        [Datum] , 
        DESC 
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        AVERAGE ( 'Table'[Avg mfcktransf7] ) , 
        ALL ( 'Table' ) ,
        _topn
    )
```

Here I have assumed that `WERK` and `Sorte_Tech` are important columns where the average must be calculated for a distinct combination of these values. If this is wrong you can reduce the code to:

```
Moving Avg = 
VAR _current_date = [Datum]
VAR _n = 2
VAR _topn = 
    TOPN ( 
        _n , 
        FILTER ( 
            VALUES ( 'Table'[Datum] ) , 
            'Table'[Datum] <= _current_date 
        ) , 
        [Datum] , 
        DESC 
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        AVERAGE ( 'Table'[Avg mfcktransf7] ) , 
        ALL ( 'Table' ) ,
        _topn
    )
```

Gives you this result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for your proposal.  [Avg mfcktransf7] is already a measure, I cant put it in the Return. The error stated is: The funktion "average" accepts as the 1. argument only a column reference. (translated on the fly).
I need this dynamic, thats why I tried to create a measure without.

Comment: Can't you then use `CALCULATE ( [Avg mfcktransf7] , ... )` ? There is no information in your question what is a measure and what isn't ;)

Comment: The measure itself I added to the description. With the CALCULATE your formula works, but shows wrong values - not expected values.